# Maximum number of messages sent to a Queue in OpenMQ?

Tags: glassfish, queue, jms, ejb, jboss-mdb

I am currently using Glassfish v2.1 and I have set up a queue to send and receive messages from with Sesion beans and MDBs respectively. However, I have noticed that I can send only a maximum of 1000 messages to the queue. Is there any reason why I cannot send more than 1000 messages to the queue? I do have a "developer" profile setup for the glassfish domain. Could that be the reason? Or is there some resource configuration setting that I need to modify?

I have setup the sun-resources.xml configuration properties as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0 Resource Definitions //EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-resources_1_3.dtd">
<resources>
  <admin-object-resource
        enabled="true"
        jndi-name="jms/UpdateQueue"
        object-type="user"
        res-adapter="jmsra"
        res-type="javax.jms.Queue">
    <description/>
    <property name="Name" value="UpdatePhysicalQueue"/>
  </admin-object-resource>
  <connector-resource
        enabled="true" jndi-name="jms/UpdateQueueFactory"
        object-type="user"
        pool-name="jms/UpdateQueueFactoryPool">
    <description/>
  </connector-resource>
  <connector-connection-pool
        associate-with-thread="false"
        connection-creation-retry-attempts="0"
        connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10"
        connection-definition-name="javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory"
        connection-leak-reclaim="false"
        connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0"
        fail-all-connections="false"
        idle-timeout-in-seconds="300"
        is-connection-validation-required="false"
        lazy-connection-association="false"
        lazy-connection-enlistment="false"
        match-connections="true"
        max-connection-usage-count="0"
        max-pool-size="32"
        max-wait-time-in-millis="60000"
        name="jms/UpdateFactoryPool"
        pool-resize-quantity="2"
        resource-adapter-name="jmsra"
        steady-pool-size="8"
        validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0"/>
</resources>
```

Hmm .. further investigation revealed the following in the imq logs:

```
   [17/Nov/2009:10:27:57 CST] ERROR sendMessage: Sending message failed. Connection ID: 427038234214377984:
    com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsserver.util.BrokerException: transaction failed: [B4303]: The maximum number of messages [1,000] that the producer can process in a single transaction (TID=427038234364096768) has been exceeded. Please either limit the # of messages per transaction or increase the imq.transaction.producer.maxNumMsgs property.
```

So what would I do if I needed to send more than 5000 messages at a time?

What I am trying to do is to read all the records in a table and update a particular field of each record based on the corresponding value of that record in a legacy table to which I have only read only access. This table has more than 10k records in it. As of now, I am sequentially going through each record in a for loop, getting the corresponding record from the legacy table, comparing the field values, updating the record if necessary and adding corresponding new records in other tables.

However, I was hoping to improve performance by processing all the records asynchronously. To do that I was thinking of sending each record info as a separate message and hence requiring so many messages.

Answer (score 2):

To configure OpenMQ and set artitrary broker properties, have a look at this [blog post](http://openmessaging.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-set-arbitrary-broker-properties.html).

But actually, I wouldn't advice to increase the `imq.transaction.producer.maxNumMsgs` property, at least not above the value recommended in the [documentation](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-6740/aeons?a=view):

> The maximum number of messages that a producer can process in a single transaction. It is recommended that the value be less than 5000 to prevent the exhausting of resources.

If you need to send more messages, consider doing it in several transactions.

Comment: I wrote a simple wrapper around a JMS connection to commit messages is blocks.  https://gist.github.com/837393

Comment: @OleTraveler I looked at your code. Does it really work that way? Closing and reopening the JMS connection doesn't start a new transaction. Therefore, your code should not work with container managed transactions.

Comment: I've posted a related question which you can eventually answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233854/how-to-send-multiple-jms-messages-in-blocks-each-in-a-new-transaction. It's about how to split up sending JMS messages in multiple transactions with container managed transactions.

Comment: The code worked for me until I used XA transactions.  I think that basically without XA transaction, you can do multiple transaction within a Session bean (kind of like Bean managed persistence.  It does not work with XA transaction though.  I think maybe if I use bean managed persistence and commit both the Session Bean's transaction as well as the JMX transaction it might work.